# Android: How to get the id of the CustomListView item fetched from database?

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi guys i am searching for a solution for this problem since 8 days still couldn't find any solution for it all the implementations which i used gave me a null pointer exception.

Well, here is the issue, i am creating an app where i am allowing the user to be able to comment on a particular item of the list-view,  on button click user will be redirected to the comments page containing the comments related to that post.

So for this I need my button to be able to get the ID of that post i can write the logic on how this id will query the database and display the comments specific to that post so

Here are my files related to this project;

**FeedListAdapter**

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private ListView lv;
    private FeedItem fi;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
        Button ops= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ops);
        name.setText(item.getName());
        ops.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity,  Post.class);

                activity.startActivity(myIntent);




            }
        });
        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);


        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    public void setMyList(List myListOfObjects) {
        this.feedItems = myListOfObjects;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**FeedItem**

```
public class FeedItem {
    private int id;
    private String name, status, image, profilePic, timeStamp, url;
    private Button but;
    public FeedItem() {
    }

    public FeedItem(int id, String name, String image, String status,
                    String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url, Button but) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.url = url;
        this.but= but;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImge() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImge(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

**FragmentOne**

```
public class FragmentOne extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String TAG = FragmentOne.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://fomains.esy.es/android_app_api/json.php";
    public  int pid;
    private Button b1;
    public CursorAdapter me;
    public ArrayAdapter my;
    int global_position =0;
    FeedListAdapter feedi;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, frameLayout);

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                global_position=position;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+global_position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF6600")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(
                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
         b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(FragmentOne.this, Post.class);

                 FragmentOne.this.startActivity(myIntent);
             }
         });
        listView.invalidateViews();
    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = feedArray.length()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);


                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));
                 pid = feedObj.getInt("id");

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));


                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);

            }

            listView.invalidateViews();
            // notify data changes to list adapater

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Well above is my code for getting the data from the database and displaying it using a custom list adapter

So guys can you help me out with this problem

Comment: Where are you getting null pointer exception? As I understand from your question, the problem is to just get the ID associated with the button clicked, for this you can setTag for each row with the ID of the feedItem and on the button click you can getTag and you will get the ID of the feedItem

Comment: @GokulKulkarni well sir in this i removed the null pointer exception its the basic code of my list view and sir can you provide a example of how to set Tag and Get Tag I get the null pointer exception when i try to store the getID methods value in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You are not using viewholder pattern, I suggest you to use ViewHolder pattern which you can use as follows,

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView timestamp;
    TextView statusmsg;
    TextView url;
    FeedImageView feedImageView;
    NetworkImageView profilePic;
    Button ops;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        viewHolder.statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        viewHolder.url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        viewHolder.profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        viewHolder.feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
        viewHolder.ops = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ops);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.ops.setTag(null);
    }
    viewHolder.ops.setTag(/*give the id whatever u want to*/);
    /* follow other part of code as it is */
}
```

In your on click method of the Button ops you can get the Tag for the same and use it to query the DB.

Hope it helps cheers!!

Comment: So should i should use this as my Feed List Adapter Right

Comment: yes, you can add ViewHolder and getView method and try.

Comment: so sir get id method will be in my ops button right sir 

I passed viewHolder in the set Tag is it right sir

Comment: In your ops button's onclick method, if you do v.getTag() then you must get the id, provided you've set it as given in the answer. v is the parameter which you get to the onClick method

Comment: so we pass the View as an argument in setTag right.

Comment: I get this error now at viewHolder = convertView.getTag();

 error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to FeedListAdapter.ViewHolder

Comment: add typecast, this is very basic thing, viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

Comment: in the setTag, you have to pass the id itself not the view. the above one is ViewHolder design pattern, its no way related to your solution, for your solution you must make sure u do
viewHolder.ops.setTag(/*give the id whatever u want to*/);
as I have mentioned in the code

Comment: Yes sir i typecast it to view holder then i get this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.myapplication.rg.myapptest.adapter.FeedListAdapter$ViewHolder

Comment: Did u do setTag in the if the statement?

Comment: I solved it sir and sir you mean to say that i need to pass the id which i get using JSON ?

Comment: Yes, if it's the same ID which will be stored in the database

Comment: well sir i created the object of FeedItem and got the ID and i set it using setTag now sir i should use the getTag value to query the database right is their any way i can know whats the value in getTag ?

Comment: Yes, tag is the attribute, you can get the value of the tag by calling getTag() method on the ops button